# Set RadioButton checked onResume

Tags: android

Creating app in which i am setting data in recyclerview list and showing that data using radiobutton in radiogroup and text.I am able to check radiobutton,but when i again open that activity my checked radiobutton is unchecked,but i want that when i again open activity my radiobutton shoulde be checked.

Here is my Adapter class :

```
holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton checked_rb = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
                    holder.radioButton.setChecked(true);

                if (lastCheckedRB != null) {
                    lastCheckedRB.setChecked(false);
                }
                if(selectedId!=0)
                {
                    holder.radioButton.setChecked(true);
                }

                //store the clicked radiobutton
                if(holder.radioButton.isChecked())
                {
                    teamList.clear();
                    lastCheckedRB = checked_rb;
                    teamList.add(name);

                    int checkedIndex = group.indexOfChild(checked_rb);
                }
                else
                {
                    holder.radioButton.setChecked(false);
                }
                int selectedId = holder.radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            }
```

Here is my Activity class :

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        adapter.lastCheckedRB.setChecked(true);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because u activity is not have focus.
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-cRgfIY8Y0pE/ToyPWqE3L4I/AAAAAAAAAbM/mfpvj5yabiA/s800/20111005_L0023_L_StatesSchema.jpg

Comment: my flow is correct,and i am able to get lastchecked item but not able to checked radiobutton